# Adding subfolders to a combobox

Tags: combobox

```
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo CustomerDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.CustDir);

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo subDir = null;

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir_loopVariable in CustomerDir.GetDirectories())
        {
                subDir = subDir_loopVariable;
                CustomerComboBox.Items.Add(subDir.Name);
        }
```

this is the code I have now that isn't working, any ideas?

Comment: what does "it isn't working" actually mean?  Does it error?  What are you expecting it to do that it doesn't?

Comment: The combobox remains empty upon loading that particular window, when it is suppose to be listing all of the subfolders

Comment: I have the original code in VB which works, but when i convert it over to C# its not listing everything in the combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:-

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo("c:/");
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in root.GetDirectories())
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(directory.Name);
        }
    }
```

which is, basically, your code; works perfectly (and loads comboBox1 with the folders in the root of my hard drive)  - so the problem is most likely to be Properties.Settings.Default.CustDir isn't pointing where you think it is.  Set a breakpoint on the first line of the code you have quoted, step into the debugger and check the value of that setting.  Then step through the code and watch it enumerate the folders.  I'm guessing your code isn't being executed - or the identity it's running as doesn't have access rights to the folder it's pointing at (if it's pointing successfully at a folder).

Comment: Probably a good idea to pick an answer and close the question.  Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("your_directory_path");
DirectoryInfo[] directories = directory.GetDirectories();

foreach(DirectoryInfo folder in directories)
  CustomerComboBox.Items.Add(folder.Name);
```